# Explorer command line switches?

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

Is there an exhaustive list of command-line switches for Windows Explorer? I know **/separate** is undocumented in this [knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510) as well as [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307856/).

Comment: Unfortunately that link is broken. Would have been better to mention the details here.

Comment: @jonschlinkert [Wayback archived copy from 2012-11-12](https://web.archive.org/web/20121112102301/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307856/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [Geoff Chappell's page about explorer's command line switches](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm). It lists all of the switches that Justin mentions along with the /idlist switch (though using this requires raw memory access, so it would probably be more interesting on SO than here on SU). The syntax for each switch is given, and some esoteric details regarding item specifiers are also explained.

Comment: It would be better to answer the question here than provide a link.

Comment: I found [Explorer.exe - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html "Explorer.exe - Windows CMD - SS64.com") helpful, it also provides a view into an (archived) official source: [Windows Explorer Command-Line Options](https://web.archive.org/web/20150602220856/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457 "Windows Explorer Command-Line Options")

Comment: There must be more options available. For example the Task Scheduler starts `explorer.exe  /NOUACCHECK` - this option is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 27):

- /separate - Launches this explorer instance as a separate process.
- /select [object] - selects the file or folder in the new explorer window
- Opens a new single-pane Window for the default selection. This is usually the root of the drive on which Windows is installed.
- /e Starts - Windows Explorer using its default view.
- /root - Opens a window view of the specified object.

Comment: It might not be obvious for the reader, but you need to append a comma after the command line switch. For instance: `explorer /seperate C:\temp` is not valid and will open a default location. You need to use `explorer /seperate, C:\temp`.

Comment: @Sebazzz FYI: it’s **/separate**, not */seperate*.

Comment: Oddly enough /seperate works just like /separate does. MS must have put in a special case for people that don't spell very well.

Answer (score 8):

I looked at my EXPLORER.EXE as per *Windows 7, 64bit* (file version 6.1.7601.17514) with the hex editor [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and searched `/SELECT` in UTF16-LE encoding and expected the other potential parameters to be around that. Why has nobody else done this before? What I found:

- `/EXPAND` - will open a specific folder and will interpret [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) in the text. Examples:

  - `/EXPAND,%windir%` will open the *Windows* folder.
  - `/EXPAND,%programfiles%\Java` will open your *Java* folder (without the hassle of spaces in the path).
- `/FACTORY` - no clue: it takes a while to start, but I don't see what has changed. Expected a factory reset of all settings, but different folder views are still intact.

The other parameters I found (`/N`, `/E`, `/ROOT`, `/IDLIST`, `/SELECT` and `/SEPARATE`) are already mentioned. I did neither find `/SEPERATE`, nor `/NOUACCHECK`. Also keep in mind: just because I found those texts doesn't mean Explorer's code also makes use of each one.

---

As per *Windows 10, 64bit* (file version 10.0.19041.844) I also found more parameters and I have no clue on any of them. The case is exactly the one found in the binary:

- `/LOADSAVEDWINDOWS`
- `/NoShellRegistrationCheck`
- `/NoUACCheck`
- `/NoShellRegistrationAndUACCheck`
- `/RunFirstLogonAnim`

Comment: A *Factory* is used to make COM objects. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/implementing-iclassfactory.

Comment: If you hit Win+R and run anything, its parent process is `explorer.exe /LOADSAVEDWINDOWS`.

Comment: @MartinBraun, that is absolutely not true, the method by which a child process is executed does not affect the child's parent process command line.

If explorer.exe was launched with only "/LOADSAVEDWINDOWS" ALL CHILD PROCESSES have a parent process command-line with that value, every other case will not, such as when I have tried just now.

Answer (score 4):

This will probably help someone.

if you are trying to open a network path that is a hidden or administrative share, e.g. ends with "$", e.g. \sharedNetworkPath\HiddenFolder$

Then this works:

`explorer.exe /root, \\sharedNetworkPath\HiddenFolder$`

but this doesn't

`explorer.exe /select, \\sharedNetworkPath\HiddenFolder$`

Comment: Thank you so much. This would not work `explorer "/select,\\server\\drive$\path\\file.xlsx"` and `explorer "/root,\\server\\drive$\path\\file.xlsx"` opened the file instead of selecting. But you answer clued me onto trying `explorer /select, "\\server\\drive$\path\\file.xlsx"` which worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Well, noUACcheck doesn't work as one might expect.  I thought it might prevent the user access chack from being displayed, but it did't in my experiment.  Neither does /NoShellRegistrationAndUACCheck.  Might be because I' running explorer under windows 7.
Trying to set a flag to allow windows explorer to open without the UAC prompt.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Windows Explorer normally *shouldn't* trigger a UAC prompt when opening. In fact, it's nigh impossible to launch an elevated explorer.exe process at all.