# Can I run 32-bit version of Explorer on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

For compatibility and testing, I would like to run a 32-bit version of Windows Explorer on 64-bit Windows Vista. Is this even possible? And if so, how do I do that?

I looked into the System32 folder and it contains the `explorer.exe` but it appears to be the 64-bit version. Is there another EXE stored in some other location that I can run, one that is 32-bit?

**Correction:**

The `explorer.exe` is stored in C:\Windows and not in C:\Windows\System32. That's what I meant.

**Update:**

Apparently the `/separate` switch is undocumented. But the `/e` switch may not be relevant for Windows Vista, only for Windows XP.

Here's what I found:

- [Microsoft KB130510](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510)
- [Microsoft KB314853](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=314853)
- [Microsoft KB307856](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307856)
- [Microsoft KB895561](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895561)
- [Superuser - Explorer command line switches?](https://superuser.com/questions/21394/explorer-command-line-switches)

For Windows Vista this should be enough:

```
%systemroot%\syswow64\explorer.exe /separate
```

The /separate switch is required to start explorer.exe as a separate process. Otherwise the 64-bit version is started.

Comment: just to be sure, you are talking about the file explorer, not internet explorer?

Comment: I did say `explorer.exe` and not `iexplore.exe`. It's called Windows Explorer for a reason. But it's also called File Explorer officially now in Windows 7 or 8 I think. Just rule out Internet Explorer.

Comment: Can someone please explain or give me a link to some TechNet article or something where `/separete` and `/e` switches are explained.

Comment: If you are still interested about the switches, [here is a explanation of them](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have not personally tested this, [it looks like it may be possible:](http://mdn.morovia.com/kb/Howto-Launch-32bit-Windows-Explorer-64bit-Windows-10610.html)

On my install, I do not have a Explore.exe in System32, only in sysWow64. Perhaps a third party download is required to make sure the application is 32bit in your system32 folder.

Comment: Okay, this worked. But I am given the code `%Systemroot%\SysWOW64\explorer.exe /separate /e, {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` and I know that `%systemroot%` is my Windows install directory, and `explorer.exe` is the program. And this is actually the 32-bit version of it. But what do the `separate` and `e` switches do? And what's that last number?

Comment: That's wrong name. It's called **explorer.exe** and not explore.exe. But yes, you are right about the location. It's in C:\Windows and not in the sub-directory C:\Windows\System32. Also make sure you type it in correctly if you are using the Run prompt, otherwise it will fail and give you an error.

Comment: To point some things out, `SysWoW64` contains **32-bit** executables and libraries, for use with Windows-on-Windows (the technology that allows 32-bit apps to run on 64-bit windows). `System32` is a generic system folder, and despite the name, should contain executables and libraries that match the system architecture: **64-bit on W7 x64, and 32-bit on W7 x86**.