# What .exe gets called when I press Win+PrintScreen?

Tags: windows, print-screen

For reference: this is a quick way to take a screenshot and have it saved in your Pictures folder (or elsewhere).

I would like to call it from a script if possible. Are there command line arguments? Can I change the output format from the default (`Screenshot (XXX).png`)?

Comment: Have you seen Win + Shift + S? It won't solve your issue (still only goes to the clipboard), but it's a fun and useful tool.

Comment: There isn’t an executable.  As far as I know it’s a kernel keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Re *"a quick way to take a screenshot and have it saved in your Pictures folder"*: It ***also*** [wipes out](https://superuser.com/questions/463957/what-does-win-button-print-screen-do-on-windows-8#comment2893300_463957) the current content of the clipboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### explorer.exe (Windows Explorer)

But it is not called, it already runs and if it captures the hotkey, it simply facilitates the action.

When you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, then in **Resource Monitor** tool you can see that it is **explorer.exe** which saves screenshot file to its location. Moreover, if you exit **explorer.exe** using its **Exit Explorer** (hidden) menu command, this keyboard shortcut stops working.

Currently Explorer does not have any [command line parameters](https://superuser.com/questions/21394/explorer-command-line-switches) to initiate the action.

But for example using PowerShell or [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) you can send the key combination using command line. Sequence of these 3 NirCmd calls works for me:

```
nircmd sendkey lwin down && nircmd sendkey printscreen press && nircmd sendkey lwin up
```

---

Oh, and when NirCmd made it into the answer, you can save the entire screenshot simply by its [savescreenshot command](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/savescreenshot.html):

```
nircmd savescreenshot d:\screenshot1.jpg
```

The above linked documentation says:

> savescreenshot [filename] {x y width height}
>
> save the screenshot of current screen into the specified image filename. The following file formats are supported: .bmp, .gif, .png, .jpg, .tiff
>   You can also specify `*clipboard*` instead of real filename if you want to save the screenshot into the clipboard.
>
> This command only works on Windows XP/2003/Vista (GDI+ is required)
>
> You can also specify 4 optional parameters - x, y, width, and height, if you want to save only a part of the screen.